# How can I prevent to one finger scrolling for listview control in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I want to enable just two finger scrolling. I am developing uwp application on windows 10.How can I prevent to one finger scrolling for listview control in uwp?

Bests

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is possible. It is horrendously difficult to change the ScrollViewer behavior in any way, and anything custom usually requires terrible hacks or a completely custom control to be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably do that, but I won't help you since that would be an evil feature that would confuse the users of your app. Instead, you should consider alternative solutions to whatever you'd like to happen when users use a single finger in a `ScrollViewer`.

Note that you're essentially trying to change how the `ScrollViewer` in the `ListView` template behaves. In most cases, you do that when you want to drag an item out of a list. Most people either handle the press and hold (aka long holding - the `Holding` event) or a cross-drag (dragging perpendicular to the `ScrollViewer` panning direction) and call [`ScrollViewer.CancelDirectManipulations()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.canceldirectmanipulations.aspx) to stop panning and handle drag & drop instead.

If you just want a single finger panning to stop working - then you should not do that.